# Delphi - TFrame How to save and load component properties

Tags: delphi

I have a TForm which contains a lot of `TFrame's` and i want to be able to save all properties like `TEdit.text`, `TCheckbox.checked` and so on of the `TFrame's` to one shared storage. How do i accomplish that with `TJvFormStorage` and `TJvAppIniFileStorage` ?

Workflow is the following:

1. Create a VCL Form, place a `TJvAppIniFileStorage` there, set the `FileName` property.
2. Create a VCL Frame, place a `TjvFormStorage` there, set the `AppStoragePath` property.
3. Add a TEdit onto the frame and add the `.text` property to the `TJvFormStorage` with the Form Storage Designer.
4. Add the Frame to the palette.
5. In the VCL Form, add the VCL Frame.

I tried to make it happen with passing a `TJvAppIniStorage` created in the `TForm` to the `TFrame's` and to set the `.AppStorage` of the `TJvFormStorage` property at runtime. This did not save the predefined properties, but `writeString` worked.

```
// FormShow event of the Main Form
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frFrame.init(fs_AppIniStorage); // fs_AppIniStorage is the component on the MainForm
end;

// The init function of the TFrame
procedure TfrFrame.init(var FormStorage : TJvAppIniFileStorage);
begin
  fs_FrameStorage.AppStorage := FormStorage;
  fs_FrameStorage.WriteString('test','test'); // <- is written into the storage
end;
```

This has written the following into the file:

```
[Test] // fs_FrameStorage.AppStoragePath
test=test// fs_FrameStorage.WriteString
```

Also i tried to manually save and load the component properties with:

```
fs_FrameStorage.SaveFormPlacement; // At .FormClose of TMainForm 
fs_FrameStorage.RestoreFromPlacement; // At TfrFrame.init
```

After this the file looked like that:

```
[Test] // fs_FrameStorage.AppStoragePath
test=test// fs_FrameStorage.WriteString
FormVersion=0 // new
```

Then I tried to set the `TFrame.fs_FrameStorage.AppStoragePath` in `TMainForm` in the Delphi Designer.

[image: MainFormProperty]

Which resulted into the same.

Calling `StoredProps` results in the entered `edit.text`:

```
ShowMessage(fs_FrameStorage.StoredProps.Text);
// Shows ed_Frame.text
```

When I add both components on the Same `TForm`, `TMainForm` in this case, it works as expected, saving all entered properties. But I can't access the `Frames` child components from the `MainForm` with the `TJvFormStorage` placed in the `MainForm`.

Comment: Being already a long time member of SO, you should know what is needed for a good question post. 1) A question. What exactly do you want us to answer? 2) Details about the issue you are asking about. 3) A minimal reproducible example. You can read about [mre] in the help.

Comment: I don't have the JVCL components, so I don't know if the problem is with those (I doubt it), but your claim *But I can't access the Frames child components from the MainForm.* is generally not at all correct. E.g. if I have a form with a `TEdit` and a frame (also with a `TEdit`) I can write `Form1.Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Frame31.Edit1.Width);` in a button click even handler of the form.

Comment: @TomBrunberg clarified, that the access is not possible with the Form Storage Designer of the TJvFormStorage component.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to store properties of GUI controls? Are you perhaps using GUI controls as a proxy for a proper data model?

Comment: Ok, if you say so. As I don't have those components (and will not get them either) I can't help you further. If what you have tried doesn't work, you need to find another way to do what you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wanted to simplify saving the selected tabsheet, sizes and file search paths, some checkboxes which hide and show some controls and text which the user enters as note for himself. But you are right, I should probably rethink the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem today, but with saving grid related properties.

As TJvFormStorage is a Class of TJvFormPlacement, calling `TJvFormPlacement.RestorePlacement` and `TJvFormPlacement.SavePlacement` worked for me.

Here my situation and solution, if anybody else falls into the same pit:

I had one main form with a TJvFormStorage (A) (working like a charm) and a panel, loaded with an external VCL-Frame at runtime, including a TjvUltimGrid. The goal was to load and save the grid-properties into the same AppStorage.

1. I added a new TJvFormStorage (B) on the frame with the same AppStorage like the main form and set the AppStoragePath by hand
2. Checking the Options for fpState/fpSize/fpLocation
3. Then called `TJvFormPlacement.RestorePlacement` on Storage B after loading the frame
4. As wells as `TJvFormPlacement.SavePlacement` on the close event of the main form